# What is the safest way to split a "Floating Point Number String" into its Whole and Fractional Parts

Tags: javascript, floating-point, numbers, rounding

I have developed the following short function to split a number passed to it **in a string format** into its *Whole* and *Fractional* Parts (also outputted as strings).

***Note1: The Whole part of the number can run into large numbers (in excess of 50 digits).***

***Note 2: The output result (the Whole and the Fraction strings) will not be converted into an integer or a float but will be further manipulated only as a string due to the Javascript rounding for large numbers. So going back to numbers is not a concern here***

Because the function detects the machine's locale automatically, it is therefore expected that **the user enters (passes) the number in the locale of his local machine** or otherwise the number is generated programmatically and passed to the function.

The number is expected to be passed as a "string" due to the very large length and also because there is no handling for numbers passed in exponent (e) format.

The function uses the toLocaleString() to detect the decimal and thousand separators.

I have tested the function with the major number systems (.,' space) and so far, so good.

The question is, **how safe will this code be**, and are there any alternative better and safer methods to do it or corrections/changes necessary?

Thanks

```js
 function splitFloatString(NumString) {
    var decimalSeparator  = (1.1).toLocaleString().substring(1,2);  // Get Decimal Separator
    var thousandSeparator = (1000).toLocaleString().substring(1,2); // Get Thousands Separator
    NumString += "";                                                // ensure a string
    var fraction ="0";                                              // default no fractional part
    NumString = NumString.replace(RegExp("\\"+thousandSeparator,"g"),"");   //remove thousand separators if any

    if (RegExp("\\"+decimalSeparator,"g").test(NumString)) {        // test for decimal separator
       var n = NumString.split(decimalSeparator);                   // Split at Decimal Seprator
       NumString = n[0];                                            // The Whole part
       if (n.length==2) fraction = n[1];                            // The Fractional part
       if (fraction=="") fraction ="0";
       }

  console.log("Whole: ("+NumString+"), Fraction: ("+fraction+")");  // added for testing
  //return n=[NumString,fraction];                                  // normal return uncomment
}

 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 // Tests assuming user's machine and user enters/passes US-EN separators as an example
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        splitFloatString("123456789123456699999887788812340786.45678907656912574321115194123123456789");
        splitFloatString("1,234,567,891,234,566,999,998,888,812,340.456520754186789075194123123456789");
        splitFloatString("200")
        splitFloatString("0.")
        splitFloatString(123456.2349999)
        splitFloatString("")
        splitFloatString()
```

Comment: From what environment are the inputs coming from? If from a JavaScript as well, I would suggest you encounter for exponential numbers `3.51e+41` for example.

Comment: @AhmedHammad Agree. But this would need adding code to convert exponent numbers to full string equivalents. Which is possible to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have been able to finally get the final answer I was looking for.

Thanks to all for their assistance and ideas:

```js
function numberSplit (NumString) {
  var decimalSep  = 1.1.toLocaleString().substring(1,2),  // Get Deciaml Separator
      thousandSep = 1e3.toLocaleString().substring(1,2),  // Get Thousand Separator
      fraction    = "0",                                  // Default "0"
      n = (NumString = (NumString +="").replace(RegExp("\\"+thousandSep,"g"),"")).split(decimalSep);
  NumString = n[0] ;                              // Get Whole Part
  NumString == "" && (NumString = undefined);     // Whole = undefined if empty
  n.length  == 2  && (fraction  = n[1]);          // Get Fractional part (only if 1 decimal place)
  fraction  == "" && (fraction  = "0");           // Fraction = 0 if empty

console.log("Whole: ("+NumString+"), Fraction: ("+fraction+")")
}
  
//-----------------------------------------------------------
// Ttests assuming user enters US-EN separators as an example
//-----------------------------------------------------------
numberSplit("123456789123456699999887788812340786.45678907656912574321115194123123456789");
numberSplit("1,234,567,891,234,566,999,998,888,812,340.456520754186789075194123123456789");
numberSplit("200")
numberSplit("0.")
numberSplit(123456.2349999)
numberSplit("1.2.3");           // Fractional part ignored as invalid
numberSplit("")                 // Return undefined
numberSplit()                   // Return undefined
numberSplit(NaN)                // Return NaN
numberSplit(undefined)          // Return undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

According to me, you are just complicating the whole thing unnecessarily. Here's a simple way to achieve the same result.

```js
function getLocaleSeparators() {
  const testNumber = 1000.1.toLocaleString()
  return [testNumber.substring(1,2), testNumber.substring(5,6)]
}

function splitFloatString(number) {
  const numberString = number.toString()
  const [thousandSeparator, decimalSeparator] = getLocaleSeparators()
  let [wholePart, fractionPart] = numberString.replace(new RegExp(thousandSeparator, 'g'), '').split(decimalSeparator)
  wholePart = wholePart || "0"
  fractionPart = fractionPart || "0"
  console.log(`Whole: ${wholePart}, Fraction: ${fractionPart}`);
}
```

```js
function getLocaleSeparators() {
  const testNumber = 1000.1.toLocaleString()
  return [testNumber.substring(1,2), testNumber.substring(5,6)]
}

function splitFloatString(number) {
  const numberString = number.toString()
  const [thousandSeparator, decimalSeparator] = getLocaleSeparators()
  let [wholePart, fractionPart] = numberString.replace(new RegExp(thousandSeparator, 'g'), '').split(decimalSeparator)
  wholePart = wholePart || "0"
  fractionPart = fractionPart || "0"
  console.log(`Whole: ${wholePart}, Fraction: ${fractionPart}`);
}

splitFloatString("123456789123456699999887788812340786.45678907656912574321115194123123456789");
splitFloatString("1,234,567,891,234,566,999,998,888,812,340.456520754186789075194123123456789");
splitFloatString("200")
splitFloatString("0.")
splitFloatString(123456.2349999)
splitFloatString("")
```

Comment: But you are assuming here that a comma and the dot are the separators "always".

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei Updated the answer.

Comment: thanks. The locale string detection is done in one instruction.

Comment: Passing this to the function `splitFloatString()` will break it with an error.

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? Parameters should either be with a default value if optional or always passed to the function when it expects one. Otherwise, you are doing something pretty wrong with the codebase in general. And it will leave a lot of opportunities for bugs to creep in. But if you still want, you can add a check on the start of the function and return accordingly, but I wouldn't suggest that.

Comment: The best thing you could do is, set the parameter to default as `""`, which will return both as 0. Basically, `function splitFloatString(number = "")` on the definition.

Comment: The function could be called from other codes with `undefined` numbers. Necessary to capture such cases.

Comment: The current solution is handling all the cases. Ergo, would be the safest piece to use then.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the `math.floor` function for such purposes.

It rounds the number passed as parameter to its nearest integer in downward direction:

Also, The `Math.ceil()` function rounds a number up to the next largest whole number or integer.

For other handy options, you can check out this https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-convert-a-float-number-to-whole-number-in-javascript.html

Comment: But this will round off the number and the large number of fractions will be lost

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this one. might help you.

```
number = "21212.32323";
var numberString = number + ''; // converts into string
var index = numberString.lastIndexOf("."); // get the index
var strFloat, wholeStr;
if(index === -1) {
  strFloat = '';
  wholeStr = numberString.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').replace(/ /g,'')
} else {
 strFloat = numberString.substring(index + 1); // get the decimal part
 var strWhole = numberString.substring(0, index); // get the number
 wholeStr = strWhole.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').replace(/ /g,'') // remove spcl character
}

console.log(`Whole: ${wholeStr}, Fraction: ${strFloat}`);
```

And yes you can not exceed MAX_SAFE_INTEGER in javascript i.e 32-bits.
[What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307200/9739044)

Comment: for the input `number = "212122121"` the output is: `"Whole: , Fraction: 212122121"`. i.e. the whole number is treated as fraction.

Comment: Updated the answer please check it.